# Ruby - FileUtils copy_file Permission denied on Windows

Tags: ruby

I'm making `gem` that copy files from `/template` directory (inside the gem) into the current directory of the console.

Here's what it looks like:

```
require "fileutils"

# Get the console's current directory
destination_dir = Dir.pwd

# Home directory of my gem, looks like C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/my_gem-1.0.0
home_dir = File.expand_path( "..", File.dirname(__FILE__) )

# Template directory, looks like C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/my_gem-1.0.0/template
template_dir = File.join( home_dir, "template" )

FileUtils.copy_file( template_dir, destination_dir )
```

And I got this error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `initialize': Permission denied -
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/my_gem-1.0.0/template (Errno::
EACCES)
```

I have checked that the directory does exists by running `Dir[template_dir]`.

Any solution? Thanks

**UPDATE to answer comments below**

@Babai

I added this line before `copy_file`, but still doesn't work. Am I doing it right?

```
FileUtils.chmod(0777, template_dir)
```

@mudasobwa

Here's the result of the code

```
# puts "#{template_dir} \n #{destination_dir}"
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/my_gem-1.0.0/template
C:/Users/myname/Documents/Test
```

Comment: Can you try this - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod  first ?

Comment: Would you put debugging output like `puts "#{template_dir} ⇒ #{destination_dir}"` before `FileUtils.copy_file` and show the output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added Update to the Question to answer both of you

Answer (score 2):

My bad. My `template` directory contains another folders. So I need to use `cp_r` instead of `copy_file`

```
FileUtils.cp_r( template_dir, destination_dir )
```