# Permission denied when trying to copy shared files to local drive in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is my very basic copy code:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.copy_file("\\\\winmomfs1\\3rdParty\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11gR2\\win64_11gR2_client.zip","c:\\chef-tmp")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\ctote\Desktop>ruby cp.rb C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `initialize': Permission denied - c:/chef-tmp (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `open'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `block in copy_file'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `open'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `copy_file'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
        from cp.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? I can manually copy these files through explorer, so I don't think it's a permissions thing.

Comment: have you tried copying to some other drive using the code? does it work?

Comment: use http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r And let me know

Comment: That totally worked - feel free to add it as the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`FileUtils::cp_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r) and write code as below :

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.cp_r("\\\\winmomfs1\\3rdParty\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11gR2\\win64_11gR2_client.zip","c:\\chef-tmp")
```

Look this post - [Ruby-FileUtils copy_file Permission denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469555/ruby-fileutils-copy-file-permission-denied-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: while a recursive copy when the OP is copying only a file

Comment: @bjhaid That was OP's wrong method selection.. See his comment below the post.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, it's from [the documentation for IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb"....

It fixes this:

```
FileUtils.copy_file("\\\\winmomfs1\\3rdParty\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11gR2\\win64_11gR2_client.zip","c:\\chef-tmp")
```

And turns it into:

```
FileUtils.copy_file("//winmomfs1/3rdParty/Oracle Client/Oracle_11gR2/win64_11gR2_client.zip", "c:/chef-tmp")
```